# formatting decimal number to string with comma as decimal separator in racket

Tags: racket

Is there any function in racket lang providing convertion of decimal number to string with customized formatting?

I need to format decimal to string formatted as currency style?

Example: Value `100.1` should become "`100,10 CZK"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look at `~r` for custom formatting of numbers. Use regexp-replace to substitute period with comma.

[http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=~n#%28def._%28%28lib.*racket%2Fformat..rkt%29.*~7er%29%29](http://docs.racket-lang.org/reference/strings.html?q=~n#%28def._%28%28lib._racket%2Fformat..rkt%29._~7er%29%29)

Comment: I had no clue there is racket/format module. It solves my problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can implement such a function as follows:

```
(define (decimal->string val curr)
  (let ([lst (regexp-split #rx"\\." (~a val))])
    (string-append
     (car lst) "," (~a (cadr lst) #:min-width 2 #:pad-string "0") " " curr)))
```

For example,

```
> (decimal->string 100.1 "CZK")
"100,10 CZK"
```